# Having trouble changing shape of confetti

Tags: javascript

I've found this codepen that I'm integrating on a small website I have for a project. I don't want to put too much time into it, so I'll just be using a codepen I found. I'll do some adjustments to it, like the shape.

I managed to implement it, but now I'm having trouble to change the colors and the shape of the confetti.

The colors are completely random and I'd love for this to just be simple.

Also, I can't seem to be able to change the shape. I can only adjust the size.

If anyone here feels like giving me a nudge in the right direction, that'd be great!

```
'use strict';

// If set to true, the user must press
// UP UP DOWN ODWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT A B
// to trigger the confetti with a random color theme.
// Otherwise the confetti constantly falls.
var onlyOnKonami = false;

$(function() {
  // Globals
  var $window = $(window)
    , random = Math.random
    , cos = Math.cos
    , sin = Math.sin
    , PI = Math.PI
    , PI2 = PI * 2
    , timer = undefined
    , frame = undefined
    , confetti = [];

  // Settings
  var konami = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65]
    , pointer = 0;

  var particles = 150
    , spread = 40
    , sizeMin = 3
    , sizeMax = 12 - sizeMin
    , eccentricity = 10
    , deviation = 100
    , dxThetaMin = -.1
    , dxThetaMax = -dxThetaMin - dxThetaMin
    , dyMin = .13
    , dyMax = .18
    , dThetaMin = .4
    , dThetaMax = .7 - dThetaMin;

  var colorThemes = [
    function() {
      return color(200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0, 200 * random()|0);
    }, function() {
      var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(200, black, black);
    }, function() {
      var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(black, 200, black);
    }, function() {
      var black = 200 * random()|0; return color(black, black, 200);
    }, function() {
      return color(200, 100, 200 * random()|0);
    }, function() {
      return color(200 * random()|0, 200, 200);
    }, function() {
      var black = 256 * random()|0; return color(black, black, black);
    }, function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 1 : 2]();
    }, function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 3 : 5]();
    }, function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 2 : 4]();
    }
  ];
  function color(r, g, b) {
    return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  }

  // Cosine interpolation
  function interpolation(a, b, t) {
    return (1-cos(PI*t))/2 * (b-a) + a;
  }

  // Create a 1D Maximal Poisson Disc over [0, 1]
  var radius = 1/eccentricity, radius2 = radius+radius;
  function createPoisson() {
    // domain is the set of points which are still available to pick from
    // D = union{ [d_i, d_i+1] | i is even }
    var domain = [radius, 1-radius], measure = 1-radius2, spline = [0, 1];
    while (measure) {
      var dart = measure * random(), i, l, interval, a, b, c, d;

      // Find where dart lies
      for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
        a = domain[i], b = domain[i+1], interval = b-a;
        if (dart < measure+interval) {
          spline.push(dart += a-measure);
          break;
        }
        measure += interval;
      }
      c = dart-radius, d = dart+radius;

      // Update the domain
      for (i = domain.length-1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
        l = i-1, a = domain[l], b = domain[i];
        // c---d          c---d  Do nothing
        //   c-----d  c-----d    Move interior
        //   c--------------d    Delete interval
        //         c--d          Split interval
        //       a------b
        if (a >= c && a < d)
          if (b > d) domain[l] = d; // Move interior (Left case)
          else domain.splice(l, 2); // Delete interval
        else if (a < c && b > c)
          if (b <= d) domain[i] = c; // Move interior (Right case)
          else domain.splice(i, 0, c, d); // Split interval
      }

      // Re-measure the domain
      for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2)
        measure += domain[i+1]-domain[i];
    }

    return spline.sort();
  }

  // Create the overarching container
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.style.position = 'fixed';
  container.style.top      = '0';
  container.style.left     = '0';
  container.style.width    = '100%';
  container.style.height   = '0';
  container.style.overflow = 'visible';
  container.style.zIndex   = '9999';

  // Confetto constructor
  function Confetto(theme) {
    this.frame = 0;
    this.outer = document.createElement('div');
    this.inner = document.createElement('div');
    this.outer.appendChild(this.inner);

    var outerStyle = this.outer.style, innerStyle = this.inner.style;
    outerStyle.position = 'absolute';
    outerStyle.width  = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
    outerStyle.height = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
    innerStyle.width  = '100%';
    innerStyle.height = '100%';
    innerStyle.backgroundColor = theme();

    outerStyle.perspective = '50px';
    outerStyle.transform = 'rotate(' + (360 * random()) + 'deg)';
    this.axis = 'rotate3D(' +
      cos(360 * random()) + ',' +
      cos(360 * random()) + ',0,';
    this.theta = 360 * random();
    this.dTheta = dThetaMin + dThetaMax * random();
    innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';

    this.x = $window.width() * random();
    this.y = -deviation;
    this.dx = sin(dxThetaMin + dxThetaMax * random());
    this.dy = dyMin + dyMax * random();
    outerStyle.left = this.x + 'px';
    outerStyle.top  = this.y + 'px';

    // Create the periodic spline
    this.splineX = createPoisson();
    this.splineY = [];
    for (var i = 1, l = this.splineX.length-1; i < l; ++i)
      this.splineY[i] = deviation * random();
    this.splineY[0] = this.splineY[l] = deviation * random();

    this.update = function(height, delta) {
      this.frame += delta;
      this.x += this.dx * delta;
      this.y += this.dy * delta;
      this.theta += this.dTheta * delta;

      // Compute spline and convert to polar
      var phi = this.frame % 7777 / 7777, i = 0, j = 1;
      while (phi >= this.splineX[j]) i = j++;
      var rho = interpolation(
        this.splineY[i],
        this.splineY[j],
        (phi-this.splineX[i]) / (this.splineX[j]-this.splineX[i])
      );
      phi *= PI2;

      outerStyle.left = this.x + rho * cos(phi) + 'px';
      outerStyle.top  = this.y + rho * sin(phi) + 'px';
      innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';
      return this.y > height+deviation;
    };
  }

  function poof() {
    if (!frame) {
      // Append the container
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      // Add confetti
      var theme = colorThemes[onlyOnKonami ? colorThemes.length * random()|0 : 0]
        , count = 0;
      (function addConfetto() {
        if (onlyOnKonami && ++count > particles)
          return timer = undefined;

        var confetto = new Confetto(theme);
        confetti.push(confetto);
        container.appendChild(confetto.outer);
        timer = setTimeout(addConfetto, spread * random());
      })(0);

      // Start the loop
      var prev = undefined;
      requestAnimationFrame(function loop(timestamp) {
        var delta = prev ? timestamp - prev : 0;
        prev = timestamp;
        var height = $window.height();

        for (var i = confetti.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
          if (confetti[i].update(height, delta)) {
            container.removeChild(confetti[i].outer);
            confetti.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }

        if (timer || confetti.length)
          return frame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // Cleanup
        document.body.removeChild(container);
        frame = undefined;
      });
    }
  }

  $window.keydown(function(event) {
    pointer = konami[pointer] === event.which
      ? pointer+1
      : +(event.which === konami[0]);
    if (pointer === konami.length) {
      pointer = 0;
      poof();
    }
  });

  if (!onlyOnKonami) poof();
});
```

Comment: Do you understand the code that you found?

Comment: Did you make sure that you have a licence to use the code? You can't just use anything that you find on your own website without infringing the author's copyright.

Comment: It was discovered on a codepen.

Comment: *"I don't want to put too much time into it"*: that might be true for many of us here.

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth It's still MIT licensed.  OP would need to at least attribute to the original CodePen to be in compliance with the license.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside `Confetto()` it's just using a `<div>` inside another `<div>` and giving it random width, height, 3D rotation, etc., you should be able to manipulate `innerStyle` and/or `outerStyle` to your liking there.

Try adding something like this to make it rounded:

```
innerStyle.borderRadius = '100%';
```

Try something like this to make it squared:

```
innerStyle.borderRadius = '0';
```

Or a combination:

```
innerStyle.borderRadius = '100% 0 0 100%';
```

You should be able to set any style property you need, by camel-casing the css name (`.border` for `border`, `.borderBottom` for `border-bottom`, `.borderBottomColor` for `border-bottom-color`, etc.). Check [this list](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) for ideas